# how can I draw a RLC circuit with a switch, using Tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz, circuits

I need to draw this circuit but I just can't incorporate the switch, so a little help would be nice :)

[image]

so far i got the same circuit **without the resistance and the switch**, i did it like this:

```
\begin{circuitikz}[american]
     \draw (0,0) to[C, l = \SI{10}{\farad}] (0,3);
     \draw (3,0) to[L, l = \SI{100}{\mu\henry}] (3,3);
     \draw (0,0)--(6,0) (0,3)--(6,3);
     \draw (6,0) to[R, l = \SI{50}{\ohm}] (6,3);
\end{circuitikz}
```

but I need to add the other elements, need some help!!

Comment: I suggest that you take a look at the [circuitikz package documentation](https://ctan.mines-albi.fr/graphics/pgf/contrib/circuitikz/doc/circuitikzmanual.pdf), section _4.20 Switches and buttons_.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See if the following scheme is close to what you after:

```
\documentclass[margin=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[american,siunitx]{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{circuitikz}
\ctikzset{capacitors/width=0.1}
\node[spdt, xscale=-1] (sw) {};
\draw   (sw.in)     node[above] {S}
                    -- ++ (1,0)
                    to [C=$C_1$, name=Csign] ++ (0,-3)  coordinate (aux1)
        (Csign.north west) node[above] {$+$}
        (Csign.north west) node[below=1mm] {$-$}
        (sw.out 2)  node[below] {b}   
                    -- ++ (-0.5,0)          coordinate (aux2)
                    to [L=$L_1$, -*]    (aux1 -| aux2)
        (sw.out 1)  node[above] {a}   
                    to [R=$R_1$] ++ (-3,0)  coordinate (aux3)
                    to [battery2, v_=$\epsilon$]    (aux3 |- aux1)
                    -- (aux1);
    \end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

**Edit:**
Added is minus sign at capacitor. Both signs are inserted manually. They can be also added by replacing

```
                    to [C=$C_1$, name=Csign] ++ (0,-3)  coordinate (aux1)
        (Csign.north west) node[above] {$+$}
        (Csign.north west) node[below=1mm] {$-$}
```

with

```
                    to [C, v^=$C_1$] ++ (0,-3)  coordinate (aux1)
```

however to my taste in this case they are too far from capacitor symbol.

[image]

Comment: @jsbibra, you are right. I forgot on it. Now is corrected and also described possible writing of signs by use of `v=....` option in branch with capacitor.

Comment: thank you so so much! i'm just new at this LaTeX thing i really needed that circuit. right now i'm trying to add a modification but it's not working.  I wanna change the switch for node[cute spdt mid]. is it to much if i ask you for help again??

Comment: @RonnyGranados, for this help I also have to look in the package documentation. So try to read instruction yourself or ask new question. I haven't any idea how you try to modified suggested solution. This modification should work out of the box. So, please ask new question and show us what you try to do.